# MSMQ messages disappear for local System

Tags: msmq

I am using non transnational MSMQ message and all the message are being received in Queue but after 1-2 minutes all the message being disappeared and this is happening on iis application 2.0 and the same thing working fine using visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue looks resolved using below code and there is no IIS setting it was code issue:

// Peek and format the message.

```
        msgQueue.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();

        Message myMessage = msgQueue.Peek(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3));

        MailMessage mailMessage = (myMessage.Body as erializeableMailMessage).GetMailMessage();
        if (SendMail(mailMessage))
        {
            msgQueue.Receive();
        }
```